# Help with regex html plus with extra string at the end

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to find HTML tags, via PHP ereg, that has a `{xxx}` right before the closing tag - where `xxx` can be `[A-Za-z0-9_\-]*`.

For example: `<p>xxxx</p><p>yyyy{asdf}</p>`

This is the best I could come up with: `/<([\w]+)([^>]?)>([^{]*)\{([^}]+)\}<\/\1>/is`

The problem is though, that it will match group 3 will have `xxxx</p><p>yyyy`, and I only want `yyyy` in this case.

Hope anybody can help, cheers, Egil.

Ps. Sorry for the useless title, could not think of anything better.

Comment: Never ever parse HTML with regex. Please check out DOMDocument from php.net

Comment: @Mike You forgot the obligatory link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: The `ereg_*` suite has been deprecated for years and soon to be removed. Please use the [PCRE functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)

Comment: Phil, thanks, it is actually PCRE im using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `?` after each `+` and `*` in your regex. This will make the match less greedy.

Else try adding `<>` to the negative character classes `[^{<>]*` and `[^}<>]*` to exclude tags in between there.

Comment: Thanks. Wont that exclude nested tags though?

Comment: Yes. I assumed that you only want text content there.